# Service error: Spreadsheets (line 8, file "macros")

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I keep getting the message "Service error: Spreadsheets (line 8, file "macros")" in the following script;

(it is referring to `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(8, false);`)

```
function Update() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3:H27').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C3:H27').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(8, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C45:H60').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C45:H60').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H45').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(8, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C67:H76').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C67:H76').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H67').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(8, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:V1').activate();
};
```

Why is this happening?

Kind Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong on the google side. Refer to question earlier today. [Service Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538942/service-error-spreadsheetsline-with-setcolumnfiltercriteria)

My issue was also due to filtering, but I was not sorting, rather setting hidden values. It was also working perfectly fine yesterday until later in the evening. I would try again in a day or two. Hope that helps.