# Apply Filter to Column with Numeric Values

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a solution for filtering on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51497982/apply-basic-filter-to-multiple-values-in-a-spreadsheet-column?noredirect=1#comment90210273_51500412).

This works perfectly with a column that has string values. When I try to filter a column with numeric values it will not work. I'm assuming it is because `.setHiddenValues()` will not accept numeric values. I could be wrong.

Let me explain my scenario:

The user inputs a value on an HTML interface, let's say 6634. 
The HTML calls my function on .gs and passes the numeric value the user inputted.

```
google.script.run                                                                            //Executes an Apps Script JS Function
 .withSuccessHandler(updateStatus)                                                           //function to be called upon successfull completion of Apps Script function
 .withFailureHandler(failStatus)
 .withUserObject(button)                                                                     //To pass the event element object
 .projectSearch2(projectID);           //Apps Script JS Function
return;
```

The function (on the linked question above) will take that value and bump it up against the values in a column deleting the value if it is found. What I am left with is an array of values that I do not want filtered.

```
function projectSearch2(projectID){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var monthlyDetailSht = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet');
    var monLastCN = monthlyDetailSht.getLastColumn();
    var monLastRN = monthlyDetailSht.getLastRow();    
    var data = monthlyDetailSht.getRange(1,1,1,monLastCN).getValues();//Get 2D array of all values in row one
    var data = data[0];//Get the first and only inner array
    var projectIDCN = data.indexOf('Project Id') + 1;

    //Pull data from columns before filtering
    var projectIDData = monthlyDetailSht.getRange(2,projectIDCN,monLastRN,1).getValues();

    //Reset filters if filters exist
    if(monthlyDetailSht.getFilter() != null){monthlyDetailSht.getFilter().remove();}

    //Start Filtering
    var projectIDExclCriteria = getHiddenValueArray(projectTypeData,projectID); //get values except for    
    var rang = monthlyDetailSht.getDataRange();
    var projectIDFilter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(projectIDExclCriteria).build();//Create criteria with values you do not want included.
    var filter = rang.getFilter() || rang.createFilter();// getFilter already available or create  a new one

    if(projectID != '' && projectID != null){
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(projectIDCN, projectIDFilter);
    }


};

function getHiddenValueArray(colValueArr,visibleValueArr){
  var flatUniqArr = colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})
  .filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) ==-1); })
  return flatUniqArr;
}
```

That array is used in `.setHiddenValues()` to filter on the column.
Nothing is filtered however. This works for all columns that contain string values, just not columns with numeric values. At this point I'm lost.

Attempted Solutions:

- Convert user variable to string using `input = input.toString()`. Did not work.
- manually inserted `.setHiddenValues` for projectIDExclCriteria. Like this: `var projectIDFilter = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues([1041,1070,1071,1072]).build();` That succeeded so I know the issue is before that.
- Step before was calling getHiddenValueArray. I manually inserted like so: `var projectIDExclCriteria = getHiddenValueArray(projectIDData,[6634]);` It is not working. Is the issue with that getHiddenValueArray function not handling the numbers properly?

Here is a solution. Changing the following:

```
.filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i &&    visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) ==-1); })
```

To:

```
.filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e) == i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e) == -1); })
```

That works! Thank you Tanaike. The next question is will this impact columns that are not numeric. I have tested that and it works as well.

Comment: I think that about ``a.indexOf(e.toString())``, if ``e`` is number and ``e`` is included in ``a``, ``a.indexOf(e.toString())`` is ``-1`` by ``e.toString()``. So how about trying to modify to ``return (a.indexOf(e) == i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e) == -1)``? But I'm not sure about the detail values. So if this ``getHiddenValueArray()`` still didn't work, in order to confirm your issue, can you provide a sample value of "colValueArr" and "visibleValueArr"? And if there is the issue at ``setColumnFilterCriteria()``, can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Or if you want to use ``return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) ==-1)``, how about trying to modify from ``colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})`` to ``colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})``?

Comment: @Tanaike Your recommendation in your first comment worked. I have updated my question to include the solution. Do you want to submit an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: Thank you for replying it. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40849369/how-to-filter-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
.filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) ==-1); })
```

#### To :

```
.filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e) == i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e) == -1); })
```

#### Note :

- In this modification, the number and string can compared using each value.
- If you want to use `return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) ==-1)`, you can achieve it by modifying from `colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})` to `colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})`.

  - In this modification, `colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})` converts the number to string, so the number is used as a string.

#### Reference :

- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I can confirm this works with both numeric and string data. Question though. If I would like to search for the word "apple" in a column that has phrases such as "I ate an apple" this will not return that row. How can I get it to work that way?

Comment: also, is there a negative to using either of these over the other?

Comment: @Danilo Cuellar Thank you for your response. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Although I read your question again, I cannot understand about your other 2 issues from your reply. So in order to correctly understand about your issues, can you provide the sample situation including the input and output values you want as a new question? By this, it will help many users including me think of the solution. I would like to solve your issues. But the reason that I cannot understand about your other 2 issues is my poor skill. I'm really sorry for this situation.

Comment: how can I edit this to handle case sensitivity? I went with `colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})` approach but it does not capture if it looks for "apple" in "I ate an Apple"

Comment: Here is a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673945/search-array-of-strings-that-have-commas-within) as requested.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for your response. I saw it just now. An answer has already been posted. I think that the answer is a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I liked the solution. I'm going to post another questions for something similar. Hopefully someone with the same requirements will stumble on these questions and find them useful.

Comment: I just did a thorough review of the results and it is not returning all of the expected values. `colValueArr` has 943 values while `visibleValueArr` has 288. This is supposed to return the 655 `colValueArr` values that are not in `visibleValueArr`. It's only returning 467. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: @DanCue I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand what you want to do. Can you provide more detail information?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had an issue with numbers missing. It's resolved now. Thank you.

Comment: @DanCue Thank you for replying it. I'm sorry I couldn't help.