# Search Array of Strings with Non-sensitivity and Non-exact Match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

> Notice: I have made a few changes to the original question as my problem was not with commas within string.

I have a function I've been working on to exclude a cell value from a new array that contains a string I am searching for. I am doing this in order to put together a list for [`.setHiddenValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#setHiddenValues(String)), since `.setVisibleValues` is not supported/implemented yet.

Here are my requirements for the sake of clarity:

Currently working:

- Able to handle numbers as well as strings
- Can search for lowercase and uppercase. `visibleValueStr` is user inputted so it can't be so sensitive.
- `colValueArr` may have strings with commas within.

Still working on:

- `visibleValueStr` can be a single value or array.
- Case sensitivity("apple" to match "Apple")
- Not exact matches("apple" to match "apple and banana")

Here is the function I currently have with the above met/unmet conditions:

```
function getHiddenValueArray(colValueArr,visibleValueArr){
  var flatUniqArr = colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})
    .filter(function(e,i,a){
      return (a.indexOf(e.toString())==i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e.toString()) == -1);
    })
  return flatUniqArr;
}
```

Please let me know what other info I need. I will update this question as I continue to do my research in the meanwhile.

Clarification from comments:

User inputs input(s) on HTML form and the variable is passed on as `visibleValueArr`.

When using `Logger.log(visibleValueArr)`.

```
[apple, banana]
```

When using `Logger.log(colValueArr)`.

```
[[Apple],[apple][apple][apple and banana],[apple],[banana, and apple],
  [apple, and banana],[orange],[orange, and banana],[kiwi],[kiwi, and orange],
  [strawberry]]
```

So when I use:

```
SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(newArray).build();
```

`newArray` should be the hidden values. In this case it should be:

- orange
- kiwi
- kiwi, and orange
- strawberry

Basically anything that does not contain what `visibleValueArr` is.

Instead, it returns all values back, hiding them all.

When I use `[Apple, Banana]` the "Apple" and "Banana" values are left out of newArray as they should be, but "Apple and Banana" and "Apple, and Banana" are not"

In addition, I would also like to understand what the `e,i,a` in `function(e,i,a)` represent. I'm trying to apply `.toLowerCase()` in different places to see if that resolves part of my issue but I'm not sure where to do it.

Comment: I suggest you opt to do less in one-liners and perform proper input sanitization. If you're having a lot of trouble trying to store input into and then search an array for existing data, then perhaps try using something that isn't an array?

Comment: @tehhowch the input being looked for is provided by the user so it will sometimes be an array and other times be a single value. Sometimes they will use all lowercase, other times they will not. I would not be opposed to using more than a one-liner. What do you mean by proper input sanitization?

Comment: @I'-'I Ok. I've updated the question with examples. Let me know if you still need logs.I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @I'-'I yes, input is passed as `visibleValueArr` from an html form. I'm trying to get you the log but from my experience I can't get a log without running it through scripts. I have functions referencing other functions and passing variables so if I run the function through script it will not have the variables passed.

Comment: @I'-'I Will using `Browser.msgBox(visibleValueArr)` and `Browswer.msgBox(colValueArr )` give you what you need?

Comment: I getting the logs through `Logger.log()` now. Updating my post.

Comment: @I'-'I I've updated. I'm beginning to get a better understanding. I think newArray is coming out as a 1-D array when I need it to come out as a a 2-D array. This will avoid errors with strings that have a comma within. Am I correct?

Comment: @I'-'I It returns all items back. `[Apple, Banana, ...etc]` I'm assuming the case sensitivity is an issue. When I use "Apple" and "Banana" those are excluded but "Apple and Banana" and "Apple, and Banana" are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issues:

- Case sensitivity("apple" to match "Apple")
- Not exact matches("apple" to match "apple and banana")

#### Solution:

- Use regex-search with case insensitivity

### Modified Script:

```
    function getHiddenValueArray(colValueArr,visibleValueArr){
      /*colValueArr = [["Apple"],["apple"],["orange"],["Apple, and Banana"]];
      visibleValueArr = ['apple','banana'];*/
      var flatUniqArr = colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toString();})
        .filter(function(e,i,a){
          return (a.indexOf(e)==i && !(visibleValueArr.some(function(f){
            return e.search(new RegExp(f,'i'))+1;
          })));
        });
      //Logger.log(flatUniqArr); will log orange
      return flatUniqArr;
    }
```

#### References:

- [String#search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)
- [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I am getting this error `Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot find function some in object . `

Comment: Weird. It did log like that. Your code works when I uncomment.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. I'll report back. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Ok. I have a few columns that I run this on. I was running this function on all the columns and a couple of them were failing. I ran them individually and all but two are working perfectly. Here is the error on one: `Execution failed: SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier +.` Example: `Apple + Banana` I'm guessing this interferes with the RegEx? The second one looks a little more complicated because it is a very different. I can post another question on it if necessary. Essentially, it is a column with a `title: lastname, firstname: firstname.lastname@company.com`.

Comment: There are about 7 in the cell separated by control+enter (new lines) and with 3 control+enters before the first.

Comment: `colValueArr` is 2-D and `visibleValueArr` is 1-D? What if `visibleValueArr` comes in as 2-D? I noticed while playing with this that it errors out if `visibleValueArr` has `+` but not if the `colValueArr` has it. Just wondering if the error can be avoided if it was a 2-D array?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @I'-'I I think that ``a.indexOf(e)==i`` can be removed. ``a.indexOf(e)`` is always ``i``, because it just confirms the existence of each element from ``colValueArr``. By removing it, the process cost can be lower. If this is my misunderstanding, I'm sorry.

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for replying. I could understand about it. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer, because I had already upvoted.