# How to auto select range from a filter without having to manually enter it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, filtering

I am wondering if there is a way to auto select the cell range based on selected filter.

Example:
[image: Sample]

- Set Filter in (Column H)
- Auto select the result cell data starting Column A (A2000): Column C (C5000) etc. --- This is where I am getting stuck. I do not know how to write to auto select the result cell data  based on the selected filter.

Currently, my workout is to manually enter the cell so I could move on with writing the codes. I hope I am making sense above.

---- Code----

```
function ColHtoActive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current');  
  var crange = sheet.getRange('A7:I7350').activate();                                
  var currentCell = sheet.setCurrentCell(sheet.getRange('H7'); 
  var hSfilter = sheet.getRange('A7:I7350').createFilter(); 
  var ccC1 = sheet.getRange('H7').activate();
  var cCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues('Inactive']).build(); 

  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(8, cCriteria);    
}

function copycolA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('A');
  ss.getRange('A2307').activate();
  ss.getRange('A2307:A7155').copyTo(
      ss.getActiveRange(),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
      false);
}
```

Comment: What kind of filter have you set? And you want the filtered range?

Comment: I have added sample screen shot and edited the code. I have pasted the wrong code earlier. The code above after H7 has been activated and filter is set to "Active", I would like the code to be able to select the range automatically without manually entering the range. My next function is to copy the data into another tab based from the Active result range. I used "ss.getRange('A2307').activate();
   ss.getRange('A2307:C7155').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);" Is there a way for the code to auto select "A2307:C7155" without manually entering it?

Comment: How do you get the number 2307 and 7155, without manually entering ? In your current question, I cannot see whatever I can refer to to get these 2307 and 7155 out. What's the meaning of 2307 and 7155 ? Are they some random number ? In the picture you provided, if I select "Active" at H2, which range should be selected, and why ? if I select "Active" at H242, which range should be selected, and why ?

Comment: ('A2307:A7155') is the result of the range after you set the filter to Active. For the provide sample this would be (A23:A2288). What I am noticing now is that when it get copies to another sheet, it appears that it just copies and pastes the entire data from A23:A2288 (Filter is set only for Active rows but it also includes Inactive rows). What I would like (or hoping) to the code to do is after H2 is filtered to Active, select the result A23: A2288 (A23:B2288...or whatever range) automatically then copy/paste the value into another tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the filtered range dimensions from `getFilter().getRange()`. This will copy all the filtered range:

```
function copycolA() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Current');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('A');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getFilter().getRange();
  sourceRange.copyTo(
    targetSheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);
}
```

#### To read:

- [Filter#Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#getRange())
- [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820836)

Note that `.getValues()` or other script operations will NOT get the filtered only, but all of the values.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works for exactly what I am looking for, just to copy the result of the filtered range.

Comment: One more question: Is there a way not to include the header name from the source sheet when copying to another sheet?

Comment: @JMR You can just [deleteRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer)) after pasting... Also, If `H7` is the filter title, Just use `A8:A` to getRange... (without filter.getRange()) Only filtered row will be copied(not tested)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just copied the entire value (per your code above) and modified the target sheet code. After the data is copied, I added codes to delete the columns I don't need. It works for now. I am new at this and it is very exciting for me to learn it. Thank you for you time and help!

Comment: @JMR Also look into [`offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))

Comment: @JMR Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820836/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

```js
function myFilter() {
  const ss      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        sht     = ss.getSheetByName("Current"),
        rng     = sht.getDataRange(),
        rawData = rng.getDisplayValues();

  let filterValues = ["Inactive"],
        col = 8, // column "H".
        out = rawData.filter(dataFilter);
        out = [rawData[0], ...out]; //Add headers to filtered data 
  
  function dataFilter(arr) {
    return filterValues.includes(arr[col-1]);
  }

  const osh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("A"); 
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange(1,1,out.length,out[0].length).setValues(out);
}
```