# Copy only filtered range to other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

Hello Everybody I tried to make scripts for copying filtered data but I did not make it.

I want to copy filtered data to another sheet automatically

```
function RejectSave() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Import')

  ss.setActiveSheet(DataSheet, true);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).activate();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();

  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(['', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
    .build();

  ss.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(20, criteria);

  var SaveSheet = ss.getSheetByName('RAW')
  ss.setActiveSheet(SaveSheet, true);
  ss.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(ss.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(), 5);

  var SaveRange = SaveSheet.getRange(SaveSheet.getLastRow()+2, 1)

  DataSheet.getRange(2, 1, DataSheet.getLastRow(), 26)
    .copyTo(SaveRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  DataSheet.getFilter().remove();
};
```

but the script cannot bring just filtered data, it brings all data in that range, whether it meets the filter criteria or not.

I want to copy just filtered data!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto select range without having to manually entering it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212388/how-to-auto-select-range-without-having-to-manually-entering-it)

Comment: Note that your code makes very unnecessary use of `setActiveSheet` and `getActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filter criteria is known before writing a script, then you probably should use [JS array `filter()` method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-filter/) instead of Google sheet `getFilter()`. For example, the following function filters the source range A1:C10, excluding the rows with special values in column C. As a result it sets new (filtered) data array at start cell E1 (see also image).

```
function filtered() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get full (non-filtered) data
  var values = sheet.getRange('A1:C10').getValues();

  // Apply filter criteria here
  var hiddenValues = ['', 'A', 'B', 'C'];
  values = values.filter(function(v) {
    return hiddenValues.indexOf(v[2]) == -1;
  });

  // Set filtered data on the target sheet
  sheet.getRange(1, 5, values.length, 3).setValues(values);
}
```

JS filtering is flexible and rather quick.

[image]

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/459863 shows how this can be more natively accomplished with the `Range.copyTo` method.