# Copy only filtered range to other sheet with starting range at column B instead of column A

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a similar questions here. Could anyone help me to solve it? Here is my code first in Google sheets Macros

```
function check_closed_status_monthly_001() {
   // Replace with the name of the sheet
   var sourceSheetName = "Copy of Open Order Shared Sheet"; 
   // Replace with the name of the target sheet
   var targetSheetName = "Copy of CLOSED"; 
   // Adjust to the index of the status column (AR is the 44th column)
   var statusColumnIndex = 2; 

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    
   // Step 1: Go to the sheet
   sourceSheet.activate();
    
   // Define the range to copy (B2:P) 
   //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   // set this to B2:P, and change targetRange_04 to 15 instead of 16
   //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   var valuesToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange("B2:P").getValues();
    
   // Apply filter criteria here
   var hiddenValues = ["vouched"];
   values_04 = valuesToCopy.filter(function(v) {
     return hiddenValues.indexOf(v[1]) !== -1;
   });
    
   /*
   // Exit if there are no filtered values
      if (values_04.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
   */
   console.log(values_04)
   // Calculate the range to paste in the target sheet
   var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
   var targetRange_04 = targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow + 1, 1, values_04.length, 15).setValues(values_04);
    
   // Set the values in the target range to the copied values
   // targetRange_04.setValues(values_04);
    
}
```

Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. Here is the issue that I have

For the range part, I am trying to set the range to B2:P, however, the values at values_04 is empty (but, the values does exists in the sourceSheet, and when I set the range to A2:P, it gives me the values). My question is how do I set the range to B2:P, and make it to work.

Please refer to this link for more details! [Copy only filtered range to other sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801931/copy-only-filtered-range-to-other-sheet/76629463#76629463)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am sorry about my interpretation. When I set this to "var valuesToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:P").getValues();" 
It gives me this result = [ 1017146806,
    'closed',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    1,
    '',
    '',
    false,
    false,
    'HAM',
    1017146806,
    36122153,
    Mon Feb 13 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
    '131CC01A02:F0214',
    'CONTACTR CONTACTOR-SINGLE POLE' ]
However, I am trying to get the range from B2:P instead of A2:P, and if the code is "var valuesToCopy = sourceSheet.getRange("B2:P").getValues();", it gives me an empty [ ]

Comment: What I expect for this result should be like this ['closed', '', '', '', 1, '', '', false, false, 'HAM', 1017146806, 36122153, Mon Feb 13 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), '131CC01A02:F0214', 'CONTACTR CONTACTOR-SINGLE POLE' ], which the result won't contain "1017146806".

Comment: Would you please supply sample data.

Comment: I am sorry that I can not supply the data here. What I want is the result from column B to column P. When I set the range to column A:P, it returns me the result. However, when I set the range from column B:P, it gives me this error "Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1"

Comment: For example, I have the columns of data from Column A:P, and I set the filter range from column A:P. Then, for column B, I filtered rows only contains the text message, and then I copy the all the filtered rows from column B:P to another sheet tab.

Comment: These lines of code is written in Google Sheets macros - App Script