# How to copy filtered spreadsheet data with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

I want to copy filtered data from one spreadsheet to another.

I've got a spreadsheet with some data in column A and column B:
[image]

And I have a script that filters the data:

```
function get_data(value){
  value = 1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
  var foo_index = 1; // column A
  var filterValue = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo(value).build()

  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(foo_index, filterValue)

  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()

  Logger.log(data)

  return data
}
```

Which generates this filter view:
[image]

However, `Logger.log(data)` gives me this result:

> [[foo, bar], [1.0, A], [1.0, B], [1.0, C], [3.0, D], [5.0, D], [7.0,
>   E], [7.0, A]]

The result I want to get is:

> [[foo, bar], [1.0, A], [1.0, B], [1.0, C]]

I want this result so I can write this filtered version of the data to a new spreadsheet.

Comment: If you mean Spreadsheet and not sheet(i.e., tab), Then you can copy to sheet and then `getValues()` from it to copy to Spreadsheet. Still inelegant, but a alternative way. Elegant, but elaborate way would be to use ``sheets api`` and filter the values.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57697431/7108653

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this to work by going through each row and adding a check for `isRowHiddenByFilter`, but this seems pretty inelegant. Other ideas welcome.

```
function get_data(value){
  value = 1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
  var foo_index = 1; // column A
  var filterValue = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo(value).build()

  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(foo_index, filterValue)

  // new code
  var data = []

  for (var i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    if(!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
      var row_data = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()
      data.push(row_data[0])
    }
  }
  // end new code

  Logger.log(data)

  return data
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good enough solution and you may refer to something that these folks have done here too - https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters#TOC-Get-filtered-rows

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/459863 using the `Range.copyTo` method.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this recently as well - technically, there is a better and faster way to do this, but I believe it's currently bugged in Apps Script. Using this class https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria.html we should be able to retrieve values values chosen to show in each column and then simply `filter()` the sheet after picking the data up with `getValues()`. Doing this in the sheet itself is painfully slow, if possible it's best to never use `getValue()` / `setValue()` and instead using `getValues()` / `setValues()` and then doing whatever operation operation we were going to perform on the array in memory.

Now in this specific case, the problem is that regardless of how many or which values I filter by, I only ever see the values that I've hidden from the column, the `criteriaValues` and `visibleValues` arrays are always empty, while `hiddenValues` always shows correctly the values that are filtered out. I'm not sure, maybe I'm doing something silly here, this can be tested with something like this :

```
    var filter = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetName").getFilter();

    var criteriaValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition).getCriteriaValues();
    Logger.log("criteria Values length " + criteriaValues.length);
    Logger.log(criteriaValues);

    var visibleValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition).getVisibleValues();
    Logger.log("visible Values length " + visibleValues.length);
    Logger.log(visibleValues);

    var hiddenValues = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition).getHiddenValues();
    Logger.log("hidden Values length " + hiddenValues.length);
    Logger.log(hiddenValues);
```

So what I'm doing is iterating over `columnPosition` to get an array of `hiddenValues` which can also be used to find the rows we're interested in, but is significantly more complicated to pull off due to the fact that each subsequent filter used in sheets doesn't show `hiddenValues` for the values of rows already hidden in the previous filter.

Still faster than not doing it on an array, up until a point, which I'm guessing depends on the amount of rows and filters - I think this would not be the case if using `getVisibleValues()` (if it worked).

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(NewSht.getRange(1,1))
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is suppoed to solve the problem.