# Get row number in filtered results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im struggeling to get row-number when i have filtered rows.

How can i get the row "number", when its filtered?

currently not working:

[image]

Currently works when row-line is ascending. ( etg: 1-10).

[image]

Currently doing:

```
  var holder = [];
      for(var x = 0; x < object.length; x++) {
        var data = object[x];
        if (data[0] != '') {
         var id = x + 1;
        holder.push(use_id_to_something(data,id));
        }
    }
```

EDIT: the object that contains entire sheet

```
object = SS.getRange("A1:R").getValues();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what is `object` in your code? Because `getValues` returns all the values in the specified range regardless of the filter. For example, `sheet.getRange('A1:A18').getValues()` will return **all** the values in the range `A1:A18` regardless if you have a filter or not.

Comment: updated. it is with the formula u described. how can i make it only check for filtered? and get their row ids?

Comment: Please check the accepted answer of this question: [How to copy filtered spreadsheet data with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042502/how-to-copy-filtered-spreadsheet-data-with-apps-script)

Comment: And actually check this answer, maybe that is even more related: [How to auto select range from a filter without having to manually enter it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/11225291)

Comment: What is your desired output? To get the IDs of the filtered rows when the sheet is showing its filtered version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto select range from a filter without having to manually enter it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212388/how-to-auto-select-range-from-a-filter-without-having-to-manually-enter-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function f101() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastRow());
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let holder=vs.map((r,i)=>{if(r[0]){return r;}});
}
```