# How to get the index/row number using map in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the row number, as that row meets a couple of criteria, but:

1. I'm getting an array like this: `[,,2]`
2. I've tried using `filter()` at the end, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure how efficient that'd be, if I'm already using map going through the data to get the row:

```
ar = ["ABC", 25];

vs = [["CBA", 14],
      ["ABC", 25],
      ["DRT", 34]]

function f101() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastRow());
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let holder=vs.map((r,i)=>{if(r[0]==ar[0] && r[1] == ar[1]){return i;}});
}
```

**Expected Result:**
`1 //2nd row`

This is me trying to adapt it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110960/11832197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Array.prototype.map` use `Array.prototype.findIndex`

```js
ar = ["ABC", 25];

vs = [["CBA", 14],
      ["ABC", 25],
      ["DRT", 34]]
      
const h = vs.findIndex((r,i) => r[0] == ar[0] && r[1] == ar[1]);
console.log(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Getting the row number

```
function f101() {
  const ar = ["ABC", 25];
  const vs = [["CBA", 14],
  ["ABC", 25],
  ["DRT", 34]]
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let holder = vs.map((r, i) => { if (r[0] == ar[0] && r[1] == ar[1]) { return i + 1; } });
}
```