# apps script copies filtered rows, but duplicate them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a filtered column. I want to copy its values, clear all the original values and paste only the content of the copied filtered ones.

I try to use a draft sheet for that, but it seems not to work.
The paste repeats the filtered bulk over and over again.

(I had to add the `+300`, otherwise I get a range mismatch error).

```
function main() {
  _move(mailTab, 'F8:H', draftTab, 'A8:C');

}

function _move(fromSheet, fromRange, toSheet, toRange) {
  var fromRange = fromRange + "300";
  var toRange = toRange + "300";
  toSheet.getRange(toRange).clearContent();
  fromSheet.getRange(fromRange).copyTo(
    toSheet.getRange(toRange), { contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
  fromSheet.getRange(fromRange).clearContent();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options), `skipFilteredRows` is not a valid advanced parameter, thus it does nothing. Also, since `copyTo` always copies to a range of the same size, the filtered values are repeated.

A better way of copying filtered values is to check each row using `isRowHiddenByFilter(i)` and copy them if the condition returns false.

Sample Code is in [How to copy filtered spreadsheet data with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042502/how-to-copy-filtered-spreadsheet-data-with-apps-script)

Comment: Can you please tell why the code in my answer fixes the problem.

It copies the filtered rows only.

I manually clear data after the first duplication chunk.

Comment: It only works because your sheet's filtered data has a blank row in it. If there are no blank rows, the loop would break at the last row and no duplicate rows will be cleared.

Comment: Right, but but way has this created dups from the first place?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `skipFilteredRows` option works only with `clear()` method.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions.

`copyTo()` has no such option: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options

To copy/paste filtered data you need more complicated algorithm.

Something like this:

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var range = "A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow();
  var all_data = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();

  var filter_column = 0;
  var filter_criteria = getFilterCriteria(sheet, filter_column);

  var filtered_data = all_data.filter(row => !filter_criteria.includes(row[filter_column].toString()));
  Logger.log(filtered_data);
}

function getFilterCriteria(sheet, column) {
  try { 
    return sheet.getFilter().getColumnFilterCriteria(column+1).getHiddenValues();
  } catch(e) { 
    return []; 
  }
}
```

If you have a table like this

[image]

And if you will apply the filter that hides `1`:

[image]

You will get the `filtered data` without `1`:

```
[[2.0, bbb], [, ], [2.0, ddd]]
```

Just like it looks in the filtered table:

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell why the code in my answer fixes the problem.

It copies the filtered rows only.

I manually clear data after the first duplication chunk.

Comment: I can't say since I don't see your source data. As for your working snippet it just sweeps the wrong data under the carpet. And I think if you remove `skipFilteredRows: true` from your code it will sweep it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, why but this code fixes the problem.

It copies the filtered rows only.

I manually clear data after the first duplication chunk.

```
function _move(fromSheet, fromRange, toSheet, toRange) {
  //var fromRange = fromRange + "300";
  //var toRange = toRange + "300";  
  toSheet.getRange(toRange).clearContent();
  fromSheet.getRange(fromRange).copyTo(
    toSheet.getRange(toRange), { contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
  _clearDestinationDups(toSheet, toRange);
  fromSheet.getRange(fromRange).clearContent();
}


function _clearDestinationDups(toSheet, toRange){
  var values = toSheet.getRange(toRange).getValues();
var i;
for (i = 1; i<values.length; i++){
  if (values[i][0] == "") break;
}
toSheet.getRange(toRange).offset(i+1,0).clearContent();
}
```

Update:

```
I'm sure it copies all rows and ignores any filter. Try to apply a filter on your source data and you'll see -- all hidden rows will appear on the destination sheet.
```

My reply: I removed the filter in the source range, but the target range stays the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it copies all rows and ignores any filter. Try to apply a filter on your source data and you'll see -- all hidden rows will appear on the destination sheet.

Comment: I had this test, and it works without changing the target range.

Comment: "_I removed the filter in the source range, but the target range stays the same._" Оf course you will get exactly the same result if you remove the filter. Since your script ignores filters at all. Try to apply a filter which hides some rows in source date.

Comment: It seems you keep getting the same date from the same static`fromRange` no mater if there is activated filter of not.