# Google Apps Script to filter unique data in a filtered range

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a data similar to this one

[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HS7r.png)

First, I filtered out the range where column N is marked as yes and I success to get that. Then I want to filter out all unique value in column A together with value in column M and return the row number of the unique value. Please help me with that one.

So the result will be a range/array like this:

```
[[HCMC 1, handoi3648@gmail.com, 1 (/// row 1 of the filtered range)],
[HCMC 4, handoi3648@gmail.com, 3 (/// row 3 of the filtered range)],
[HCMC 5, handoi3648@gmail.com, 4 (/// row 4 of the filtered range)]]
```

My code upto the first filtered range as follows

```
function HouseLeaseReminderAtYE(){
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName("Tax_Master");
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange();
var Values = Range.getDisplayValues();
var hl_to_remind_at_final_range = Values.filter(function(item){return item[13]==="Y"});}
```

Comment: "return the row number of the unique value" 
If there are several values (example - HCMC 1), which row number do you want to get?

Comment: Can you clarify this `unique value in column A together with value in column M`.You mean both column A and column M should be unique? so for example if there is additional row in your sheet with [HCMC1, ...,handoi1111@gmail.com, Y] in row 8. Then the result should be `row 1,3,4 and 5 of the filtered range`?

Comment: can you share what you want your expected result to look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy filtered spreadsheet data with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042502/how-to-copy-filtered-spreadsheet-data-with-apps-script)

Comment: Dear all, Cooper's response is the solution for the case. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function HouseLeaseReminderAtYE() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Tax_Master");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  let fvs = vs.filter(function (item) { return item[13] == "Y" });
  let uO = {pA:[]};
  fvs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!uO.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      uO[r[0]] = [r[0],r[12],i+1];
      uO.pA.push(r[0]);
    }
  });
  let uA = uO.pA.map( p => [uO[p]]);
  Logger.log(uA);
}
```