# How do I use Sheets.Spreadsheets.getByDataFilter from app script for a filter view that is created in spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am seeking help with the following case

I have a spreadsheet, and it contains few filter views - `f1`, `f2`, ...

I have an app script associated with the spreadsheet. I have enabled `Resources > Advanced Google Services` to access the `Sheets API v4`.

Currently, I access that data as

```
var fruits = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("1YBPXShvssFpTI-5dPSsy_N_iEVaeHezdxymsdxpTy6w", "Fruits!A:B").values;
```

And I get the corresponding data back.
I would now, like to only get the data that is used by the filter view, so that I do not bring the entire data which is not necessary and slows down the processing.

I saw that there is something called `Sheets.Spreadsheets.getByDataFilter(resource, spreadsheetId)`, but I am not sure how to create the resource object.
Given my filters, and knowing the spreadsheet Id, how do I only fetch the data based on the filter names that I know?

**UPDATE**
My latest attempt looks like

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function getUnpostedItems() {
  Logger.log("This function will prioritize the new items that are added into the inventory");

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items");



  var filterSettings = {};
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var condition = {
    "condition": {
      "type": "LESS_THAN",
      "values": [
        { "userEnteredValue": "=NOW()-30" }
      ]
    }
  }

  filterSettings['criteria'][1] = {
    'condition': condition
  };

  var filterSettings = {
    range: {
      sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
    },
  }

  var req = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  }

  // var items = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [req]}, ss.getId());
  var items = ss.getRange("Items!A:B").getValues()
  // var items1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("1YBPXShvssFpTI-5dPSsy_N_iEVaeHezdxymsdxpTy6c", "Items!A:B").values
  Logger.log("Found items:" + items.length);


  return [];
}
```

But no luck so far!

Comment: If you want to use Sheets API, in order to use `Sheets.Spreadsheets.getByDataFilter()`, it is required to use DeveloperMetadata. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter) When you want to retrieve the values from the filtered sheet, is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697431/filter-using-setcolumnfiltercriteria-not-filtering) useful for your situation? If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to use the filter view that is already created in the spreadsheet?

Comment: This can be used for the basic filter. How about this?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that @Tanaike

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the kind of the filter you are using? If you cannot understand about this, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for your situation? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I emailed you @tanaike. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. From your script, it was found that you are using the basic filter. In this case, above sample scripts can be used for your situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201054/discussion-between-daydreamer-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1):

As per @tanaike's help, I was able to get the following working

```
function getUnpostedItems() {
  Logger.log("This function will prioritize the new items that are added into the inventory");

//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Added
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Items"); // Modified
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log("VALUES "+values.length);

  //var newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateBefore(new Date()).build();
  var newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenDateBefore(subDaysFromDate(new Date(), 30)).build();
  var range = sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, newCriteria).getRange(); //The 1-indexed position of the column.  
  // values = range.getValues();

  // I added below script.
  var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), {
    ranges: ["Items"], // <--- Please set the sheet name.
    fields: "sheets/data"
  });
  var values = res.sheets[0].data[0].rowMetadata.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (!e.hiddenByFilter && res.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[i]) {
      ar.push(
        res.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[i].values.map(function(col) {
          return col.userEnteredValue[Object.keys(col.userEnteredValue)[0]];
        })
      );
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

Logger.log("VALUES "+values.length);
  Logger.log("VALUES "+values);


  //Logger.log("Found Items:" + items.length);


  return [];
}
```