# How to get only the filtered values from a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, scripting

I have a table with some data. The first column contains IDs, a continuous series of numbers in ascending order (ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), the second column contains unsorted names (NAME: C, B, A, D, E). 
Until I apply any filters, `.getSelection().getCurrentCell().getValues()` or `.getDisplayValues()` function returns me the correct contents of the desired cells.

Then I apply filter to both columns and sort the second column alphabetically. First col becomes so: ID: 3, 2, 1, 4, 5. I select for example items from first row ( 3A ) but script returns me values that were in those cells before applying the filter ( 1C ).

So I basically need to get selected values that appears after filter was applied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter using setColumnFilterCriteria not filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697431/filter-using-setcolumnfiltercriteria-not-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

Filters are used to hide the data from view. It is not possible to get that data through any of `.get*()` methods. However, all `range.copy*()` methods will copy filtered values to the desired  range. If your use case is copying, use

- [`range.copy*()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

If you need direct access to values for  script manipulation, you can:

- `getValues()` and filter it programmatically in JavaScript or
- Use [query endpoint(`/gviz/tq`) to get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700787) or
- use [Sheets api to get the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700787/) or
- Copy filtered values to another range using `range.copy*()` and `getValues()` from the new range or