# How to filter sheet by font color and copy filtered cells without using loops?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with over 3000 rows. I need to filter one particular column by text color and then copy the filtered cells into another sheet. The new `FILTER` class allows me to filter using multiple different types of criteria, however color type filter is still not available through apps script.

I was able to go around this by using a 2nd sheet and applying a text color filter manually to it and then asking my script to go to this 2nd sheet and then copy the color filter criteria by using `.getColumnFilterCriteria().copy()` on the filtered column at sheet 2.

However, although I'm able to filter the rows I need, I also need to copy the filtered cells into a 2nd sheet, and I can't find a way to do this.

The "easiest" solution would be to use a FOR loop and check row by row using the `isRowHiddenByFilter(row)` method. However, with a 3000 rows sheet (and growing every day), going through a loop will take A LONG TIME, possibly exceeding Google Script's maximum execution time (6min).

So I'm trying to find workarounds for this, so I can be able to filter and copy only the filtered cells into another sheet without going through a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your question, the rows of sheet are hidden and shown by the basic filter. You want to retrieve the shown rows using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? And about `The "easiest" solution would be to use a FOR loop and check row by row using the isRowHiddenByFilter(row) method. However, with a 3000 rows sheet (and growing every day), going through a loop will take A LONG TIME, possibly exceeding Google Script's maximum execution time (6min).`, can you provide your script? If you can do, please add it to your question.

Comment: @Tanaike `the rows of sheet are hidden and shown by the basic filter?`: No. In my sheet, all the rows are visible, and the script applies the filter to it, hiding all the non-needed rows.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From `isRowHiddenByFilter` in your question, I thought that you use the basic filter. I apologize for this. From your replying, in your situation, the rows are hidden and shown without using the basic filter. You want to retrieve the shown rows. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Just get all of the background colors with sheet.getRange().getBackgrounds()  land the data sheet.getRange().getValues(). Loop through the the data and figure out what to do with it based upon whatever the background is

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118827 , but cannot add it without a upvote. If those answers don't satisfy you, Ask for clarification or ask a new question or [edit] your question to show why it is not a duplicate. The simple answer is `.getFilter().getRange().copyTo()` will only copy the filtered range.

Comment: Also @Cooper 's method will solve the initial problem and you won't have this issue in the first place. 3000 rows shouldn't be a big deal for looping through, if you getValues() and don't touch  the spreadsheet in loop.