# Copy to new sheet multiply itself loads of times, and dosent filter my result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

My code does copy itself, and has over 999 line rows in the result sheet, when it only should be a few lines.

When i create a filter, and tick off the "`777`" in column `F`, it also still apears in the filtered result.

**Q**: What is causing this behaviour, and how can i fix so it only copy itself once, and only the filtered results?

Here are some more details:

Full code:

```
 var partner_list = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var SS = partner_list.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var targetSheet = partner_list.getSheetByName("result");

 if (SS.getFilter() != null && SS.getFilter().toString()=='Filter') {
   console.log("have populated filter..", SS.getFilter());
var Avals_pre_D = SS.getFilter().getRange();
var Avals_pre = SS.getFilter().getRange().getValues();

    if (targetSheet) {
        partner_list.deleteSheet(targetSheet);
    } 
       targetSheet = partner_list.insertSheet();
       targetSheet.setName("result"); 
  

console.log("DATA:",Avals_pre);


Avals_pre_D.copyTo(
    targetSheet.getRange('A2:R'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(same_url).getSheetByName("result"); // aka same.. but the result sheet.
var Avals_pre = targetSheet.getRange("A2:R").getValues();    
} else {
  console.log("no filter..");
 var Avals_pre = SS.getRange("A2:R").getValues(); 
}

console.log(Avals_pre.length);
```

when trying to copy `Avals_pre` i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Avals_pre.copyTo is not a function
```

[image]

The output of `avals_pre` is as follows:

```
   DATA: [ 
    [ '','','','','','test','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','' ],
    [ 1,2,3,4,5,666,'','','',100,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','' ],
    [ 4,23,43,44,5,777,'','','',100,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','' ],
    [ 43,65,54,65,65,888,'','','',100,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','' ],]
```

( this includes the result i dont want)

If i take `Avals_pre_D` and copy that, it behaves like crazy.
where `console.log(Avals_pre.length);` equals 999.

picture of result sheet:
[image]

Comment: Would you please consider providing the context in which this code is executing? What is `ResultSheet()`?

Comment: @lamblichus its just a blank new sheet to add the filtered result with.

Comment: I meant code-related. Is this all the code you're using?

Comment: It’s more but that’s the only code I have to reproduce .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that your issue might be due to as follows.

  - When `SS.getFilter().getRange()` is used as the range,

    - When it is used with `copyTo`, the filtered values are retrieved. By this, `Avals_pre_D.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange('A2:R'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);` works for the values with the filtered result. It seems that in this case, the showing values in the range are copied.
    - When it is used with `getValues`, all values are retrieved. By this, the 1st `var Avals_pre = SS.getFilter().getRange().getValues();` works for the values without the filtered result.
  - I thought that this might be the current specification.
- And, when I saw your script, `var Avals_pre = targetSheet.getRange("A2:R").getValues();`  is used. In this case, the range is "A2:R". By this, the values are retrieved by the max row in the sheet. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue of `If i take Avals_pre_D and copy that, it behaves like crazy. where console.log(Avals_pre.length); equals 999.`.
- If you want to directly retrieve the values witht the filtered result on the sheet, I thought that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57697431) might be useful.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // var url = "###"; // I'm not sure about your "url" and "same_url". So please set these variables.
  // var same_url = url;

  var partner_list = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var SS = partner_list.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var targetSheet = partner_list.getSheetByName("result");
  if (SS.getFilter() != null && SS.getFilter().toString() == 'Filter') {
    console.log("have populated filter..", SS.getFilter());
    var Avals_pre_D = SS.getFilter().getRange();

    // --- I added below script.
    var url2 = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${partner_list.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${SS.getSheetId()}`;
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
    var Avals_pre = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
    // ---

    if (targetSheet) {
      partner_list.deleteSheet(targetSheet);
    }
    targetSheet = partner_list.insertSheet();
    targetSheet.setName("result");
    console.log("DATA:", Avals_pre);
    Avals_pre_D.copyTo(
      targetSheet.getRange('A2:R'),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
      false);
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(same_url).getSheetByName("result"); // aka same.. but the result sheet.
    var Avals_pre = targetSheet.getRange("A2:R" + targetSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();  // Modified
  } else {
    console.log("no filter..");
    var Avals_pre = SS.getRange("A2:R" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();  // Modified
  }
  console.log(Avals_pre.length);
}
```

#### Note:

- At above modified script, by following added script, the filtered values are directly retrieved to `Avals_pre`.

  ```
    var url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${partner_list.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${SS.getSheetId()}`;
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
    var Avals_pre = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
  ```
- If you can use this script, I thought that you might be able to also modify your script as follows.

  ```
    var partner_list = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var SS = partner_list.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    var Avals_pre;
    if (SS.getFilter() != null && SS.getFilter().toString() == 'Filter') {
      console.log("have populated filter..", SS.getFilter());
      var url2 = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${partner_list.getId()}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=${SS.getSheetId()}`;
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}});
      Avals_pre = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
    } else {
      console.log("no filter..");
      Avals_pre = SS.getRange("A2:R" + SS.getLastRow()).getValues();
    }
    console.log(Avals_pre.length);
  ```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- Related thread

  - [How to get filtered values from Filter after using setColumnFilterCriteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57697431)

### Added:

About the following your additional question,

> do you know how i can get the row number? etg if 3 is filtered out, i would get 1,2,4?

In this case, above method cannot be directly used. So as a simple sample script, I added one more sample script for retrieving the hidden-row numbers and showed-row numbers.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var result = {hiddenRow: [], showedRow: []};
  for (var r = 1; r <= sheet.getLastRow(); r++) {
    result[sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(r) ? "hiddenRow" : "showedRow"].push(r);
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

- In this sample script, the hidden-row numbers and showed-row numbers of the active sheet are returned.

#### Reference:

- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition)

Comment: thank you @tanaike . do you know how i can get the row number? etg if 3 is filtered out, i would get 1,2,4?

Comment: @maria Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.