# How to load last on changed Google sheet data and send an email as PDF using script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have written a script function to get google sheet data and send the email as an attached PDF. I have used here pivot tables in the google sheet.

[image]

The problem is here. after the filtered pivot table and then if I send an email.it sent only without filter data. That means is default values only export as pdf.

How to send an email pdf with current filtered data?

```
function sendEmail(){
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var getTabsheetName=ss.getSheetByName('report');

      var url = 'https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/'
      + ss.getId()  //Your File ID 
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=LETTER'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       
      + '&top_margin=0.50'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.50'          
      + '&left_margin=0.50'             
      + '&right_margin=0.50'           
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'
      + '&pagenum=false'
      + '&gridlines=false'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'      
      + '&gid='
      + getTabsheetName.getSheetId();       //the sheet's Id
     

    
    var emailsheet=ss.getSheetByName('Email');
    var emailContentsheet=ss.getSheetByName('EmailContent');
    var subject = emailContentsheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
    var n=emailsheet.getLastRow();
     
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName('Report.pdf');
    for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
      // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      var emailAddress = emailsheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var name=emailsheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
      var message = emailContentsheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
      var returnData = [name,message];
      var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
      templ.data = returnData;
      var htmlboday = templ.evaluate().getContent();
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: htmlboday,
        attachments:[blob]
      });
  }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `the filtered pivot table`?

Comment: The logic would be to copy the filtered values into a different sheet and then create a pdf out of that sheet. To find the filtered values, there are a couple of threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212388/how-to-auto-select-range-from-a-filter-without-having-to-manually-enter-it)

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated the screenshot of my pivot table

Comment: Just do the pivot table in script and I’ll put it through a temporary sheet and make a PDF of that

Comment: @Cooper Could you please give me a sample example for pivot table in script ?

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: [example of pivot table in script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539949/7215091)