# Copy values of filter criteria google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

Is it possible to copy values after applying a filter?
I want to ignore the hidden values.
I need to filter a sheet with more than 2000 rows and if I use a loop it takes a long time.
Then, I use this:

```
var filteredRangefec = range.createFilter()
.setColumnFilterCriteria(6,filterCriteria)
.setColumnFilterCriteria(9, filterCriteriafecha)
.getRange();//range.getFilter().remove();
}
```

But when i use GetValues take all values, filter and not filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the data and manipulate it in Google Apps Script, you could create *temporary* sheet, copy filtered data to temporary sheet using [method:copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed) with copyPasteType `PASTE_NORMAL`  and use [method:getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) & [method:getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getvalues) to retrieve the data.

**Example Data:**

[image: Sample Data]

I copied TheMaster answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/14606052) and added some features:

```
function getFilteredValues(){
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Temporary");
  //check if existing, delete if yes
  if (newSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
  }
  //create new sheet with name Temporary
  newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  newSheet.setName("Temporary");

  var dataSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var toFilter = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var filter = toFilter.createFilter();

  //create criteria
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
  criteria.whenNumberGreaterThan(1200);

  //filter first column using the criteria above
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria.build());

  //copy filtered data to temporary sheet
  var sourceRange = dataSheet.getFilter().getRange();
  sourceRange.copyTo(
    newSheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false); 

  Logger.log(newSheet.getDataRange().getValues());
  activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);   
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Google Apps Script Logs]

Note: You can also use this to paste the data to sheet.

Comment: a lot of unnecessary stuff going on here

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk  More likely that this method is faster than yours

Comment: @TheMaster since when is creating and deleting new sheets faster than filtering an array without unnecessary API calls?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Think about it this way: creating sheets, copyTo,getValues, deleting sheet - 4 api calls. In your answer, depending on  the number of rows, the number of api calls is unlimited. Each `isRowHiddenByFilter` makes a api call.

Comment: @TheMaster feel free to run a test and report here :) seriously, creating and deleting sheets is fast?

Comment: Hi, in noobie in program but this code work fine for me and it's really fast. I checked using an API but I am not convinced. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. You just pass the range to the `removeFilteredData()` function and it will return the filtered array.

```js
/**
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.Range} range
 * @returns {Array<Array>}
 */
function removeFilteredValues(range) {

  const values = range.getValues();
  const firstRow = range.getRow();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();

  const filteredValues = values.filter((row, i) => {
    return !(sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + firstRow));
  });

  return filteredValues;
}

function main() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getDataRange();
  
  const result = removeFilteredValues(range);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I think this would also help me, as soon as I can I try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I use from @Nikko idea above. You can copy the result to different spreadsheet.

```
function copyFilteredData(sourceID, sheetName, desID, desSheetName, filterCol, filterValue){
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // remove filter if any
  if (sheet.getFilter()) {
    sheet.getFilter().remove();
  }    

  var toFilter = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var filter = toFilter.createFilter();

  // create criteria
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
  criteria.whenTextEqualTo(filterValue);

  // filter first column using the criteria above
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(filterCol, criteria.build());

  // copy filtered data 
  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(desID);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(desSheetName);  
  var sourceRange = sheet.getFilter().getRange();
  sourceRange.copyTo(
    destSheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);

  // clear our filter before leaving
  if (sheet.getFilter()) {
    sheet.getFilter().remove();
  } 

}
```