# Copying only filtered data from a single column

Tags: google-apps-script, filtered

I am trying to copy only one column from a filtered raw file onto a working sheet. Both are sheets within the same spreadsheet.

I found this entry https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227279/17192498 which I updated for my specific sheet names. However, I do not want the entire raw file, only a specific column. How can I specify the range on the rawFile side to only be one column?

```
function filteredCopyTest (){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var rawFile = (sheet.getSheetByName('Raw'))
  var masterRoster = (sheet.getSheetByName('Master Roster'))

  var rawFileBranchFiltered = rawFile.getFilter().getRange()
  
  rawFileBranchFiltered.copyTo(
  masterRoster.getRange('AP2'),
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,
  false);

}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Do the columns change, or it's always the same column? Do the information in the column change, or it's edited and needs to constantly copy the values in the new column, or is it just for a one-time use? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: The columns are static on both sides. I could not easily reproduce the issue without using client data, and I cannot post that data on here. I thought I gave enough information, sorry.

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with something with dummy/random data.

Comment: VERY much appreciate any help. This will save me a significant amount of time.

Comment: Will you be willing to use a temp worksheet?

Comment: Yes, that shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a helper worksheet, and name it `filter_data_raw`. You can hide this worksheet, and it will not affect anything in the code.

[image]

The sample code:

```
function filteredCopy() {

  // rename the sheets with the actual name of your worksheets. 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('raw');
  const temp_targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('filter_data_raw');
  const targetSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('target');

  // gets the filter data
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getFilter().getRange();

  // copy and paste the data in the helper worksheet
  sourceRange.copyTo(
    temp_targetSheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);

  // select the column that you want to copy, in the case of my dummy data 
  // I used the column E

  let range_1 = temp_targetSheet.getRange("E:E");

  // copy the column to A1, you can use AP2 base on your code
  range_1.copyTo(
    targetSheet.getRange('A1'),
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,
    false);

  // make sure that all the values in the sheet are up to date

  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

  // clear the information on the temp sheet
  // to make sure everything ready for a new run

  temp_targetSheet.getDataRange().clearFormat();
  temp_targetSheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
}
```

Comment: @Matthew Carpenter, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: that works, thank you very much! Sorry about the delayed response; has been a very busy day.